# Display 1,2,3,4 as 1-4 in oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a requirement as- if the user selects checkboxes containing 1,2,3,4 of type 1 and 2,3 of type2 then I should display as (1-4)type1 , (2-3)type2 as the output. We have to do it in backend. I have used `LISTAGG` but couldn't achieve the desired output. The user selects the checkbox and we have the values stored in Oracle database. Any inputs will be greatly helpful.

For Ex, the following is my data.

| Type | Options |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

Using LISTAGG I could obtain :
select
Type  ,
listagg (Option, ',')
WITHIN GROUP
(ORDER BY Type) selectedOption from ( select .... )

| Type | selectedOption |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4 |
| 2 | 2,3 |

Desired Output:

| Type | selectedOption |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-4 |
| 2 | 2-3 |

Comment: You may want to look at Oracle `CASE` statements, but it's not really clear to me what you are asking. Is the user selecting this using SQL in the database? Are they selecting a value that is "1", "2", "3" or "4" or are they selecting "1,2,3,4" . Is the "backend" the database?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and needed result? As is, it's not clear what kind of data you are starting from and the logic you need to implement

Comment: Can you please add (as text, not as an image) the result you are expecting? And maybe use the preview and formatting functions provided in the editor.

Comment: This looks like GAPS AND ISLAND problem. Please share your sample data or you can directly google this term.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Yeah i have searched for GAPS AND ISLAND. Looks like that can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can try it by yourself. If you have any problem, please post some sample data here, We will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find the range boundaries and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT type,
       LISTAGG(
         CASE
         WHEN range_start = range_end
         THEN TO_CHAR( range_start )
         ELSE range_start || '-' || range_end
         END,
         ','
       ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY mn ) AS grouped_values
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY type
  ORDER BY value
  MEASURES
    FIRST( value ) AS range_start,
    LAST( value )  AS range_end,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( successive_values* last_value )
  DEFINE successive_values AS NEXT( value ) <= LAST( value ) + 1
)
GROUP BY type
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( type, value ) AS
SELECT 1, COLUMN_VALUE
FROM TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 10, 17, 3, 15, 4, 16, 5, 7, 8 ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, COLUMN_VALUE
FROM TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 2, 3 ) )
```

Outputs:

> ```
> TYPE | GROUPED_VALUES  
> ---: | :---------------
>    1 | 1-5,7-8,10,15-17
>    2 | 2-3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b641583964779370b971a832ac0a11c)*

Comment: This helped in getting the desired output.Thank you!